# Typescript : instanciate child class inside abstract class with protected constructor

Tags: typescript, polymorphism

I have a class used for create child classes with attributes that can be modified in database.
I want child classe contains only attributes like this :

```
export class Tags extends AbstractTagFactory {
    public a = "ok";
    public b = "oui";
    public premier = "tata";
    public g = 4;
}
```

I have created an abstract class :

```
import { BaseSQL, IResult } from "@caam/basesql";
import { ITag } from "./tag.interface";

export abstract class AbstractTagFactory {

    public static async create
    <T extends AbstractTagFactory>(this: {new (): T}): Promise<T> {
        const child = new this() as T;
        return await child.buildInstance() as T;
    }

    private static changeAttribute(object: AbstractTagFactory, attributeName: string, newValue: any): void {
        object = Object.defineProperty(object, attributeName, {
            value: newValue,
            writable: true,
        });
    }

    public constructor() {
        return ;
    }

    private async buildInstance(): Promise<AbstractTagFactory> {
        const sql = new BaseSQL();
        const result = await sql.executeQuery("SELECT tag, value FROM tags ORDER BY tag ASC");
        const keys: Set<string> = new Set(this.getKeys());
        const tags: ITag[] = result.recordset;
        for (const tag of tags) {
            const key = keys.has(tag.tag);
            if (key) {
                AbstractTagFactory.changeAttribute(this, tag.tag, tag.value);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    private getKeys(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(this);
    }

    private getEntries(): string[][] {
        return Object.entries(this);
    }
}
```

Here the code in the index.ts

```
async function exec() {
    const d = await Default.create<Default>();
}
exec().then(() => { process.exit(); });
```

This works good, but I want to put the constructor in protected access. 
But if I do that, typescript throw an error :

```
src/index.ts(11,21): error TS2684: The 'this' context of type 'typeof Default' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'new () => Default'.
  Cannot assign a 'protected' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.
```

Is there a way to instanciate a child class within abstract methods ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Maybe it works with [`Reflect#construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct)?!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @tao

It works using Reflect.construct()

I have just edited the create method like this :

```
public static async create
<T extends AbstractTagFactory>(): Promise<T> {
    const child = Reflect.construct(this, []) as T;
    return await child.buildInstance() as T;
}
```